# How to add a value to a key in an array?

Tags: php

I have created a cart and i am now on the checkout.  My cart array looks likes this:

```
Array ( [20] => 8 [7] => 3 [5] => 1 [4] => 1 )
```

The key is the product ID, and the value is the quantity.

How do i insert this into my orders database, **including the Product name, and price?**

I have a feeling it is a for each loop.

```
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $basketItemArray){

$addItem = "INSERT INTO order_items VALUES....         
if (!($result =  mysqli_query ($addItem, $connection))) 
die("Error creating item in addItem Query in process order");
```

I dont know how to finish off the query?

Comment: `foreach ($array as $id => $qty) { ... }`

Answer (score 0):

You can define a **`foreach`** that gives you the key (your id) and the value (your quantity).

```
foreach ($array as $id => $quantity) {
  // use $id to get product name and price
  // use qty, product name and price to create input query
} 
// send queries
```

This is horribly basic and you could have found it by simply reading the [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) documentation on the **PHP** website.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to have

```
$product = Array ( [20] => 8 [7] => 3 [5] => 1 [4] => 1 );
foreach ($product as  $p_id => $quantity)
  {
$addItem = mysqli_query("INSERT INTO order_items (product,quantity,buyer_id) VALUES ($p_id,$quantity,$buyer_id) ")
  }
```

Other way is to amend your array-

```
 $product = Array ( [0] => Array ( [0]=>20 [1]=>8)  [1] => Array ( [0]=>7 [1]=>) .....);
```

This array can be implemented using your code